# Font smoothing in wine using winetricks does not work on OS X

Tags: mac, wine, winetricks

I am using multiple wine applications on my Macbook Air running OS X El Capitan. I have tried using both Wineskin and Winebottler in creating wine wrappers for applications that I use and both of them offer the option to enable "fontsmooth=rgb" using Winetricks. However, enabling this option seems to do absolutely nothing. I have also tried enabling fontfix amongst other things to no avail. How can I get Wine to enable font anti aliasing for my apps?

Answer (score 6):

There is a better solution when downgrading XQuartz is undesirable: to disable new Truetype renderer in FreeType library by exporting FREETYPE_PROPERTIES variable to system:

1. Open terminal app
2. Go to home folder `cd ~`
3. Run `open ‑e .bash_profile` or `nano .bash_profile`
4. Add following lines:

   ```
   export FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35"
   launchctl setenv FREETYPE_PROPERTIES $FREETYPE_PROPERTIES
   ```
5. Logout and login

Comment: You saved my life!

Comment: Working on High Sierra (10.13.6), wine-4.0.2, XQuartz 2.7.11. (woot woot)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an issue with FreeType 2.7.0 that's part of XQuartz 2.7.10 and 2.7.11. Try downgrading your XQuartz to version 2.7.9 (https://www.xquartz.org/releases/XQuartz-2.7.9.html).

(Source: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=28345)

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks. In my case, it happened when I upgraded MacOS from Sierra to High Sierra (10.12 to 10.13). I assume it upgraded XQuartz to 2.7.10/11. I didn't see which I had before downgrading to 2.7.9, but now it works as usual.

Comment: This one helped
OSX Mojave 10.14.5